# How to set entityExpansionLimit in Lotus Domino Java Agent?

Tags: java, lotus-domino, lotus, agent

In developing a Lotus Domino Java agent, I received the error { ... Parser has reached the entity expansion limit "64,000"}.  I tested the base code using the command line 64bit Java and got around this issue by expanding the Java Max Heap size to 8gig and setting the -DentityExpansionLimit = 4096000.

I would like to put this entityExpansionLimit parameter into the Lotus Domino Java agent, but I cannot find where JRE parameters are set.

Any advice?

Comment: Since Java agents in Domino run in a common JVM that is owned by the AMGR task on the Domino server (on by the HTTP task in the case of Domino web agents), you can't simply add JVM parameters to an agent. It would have to be a config change somewhere on the Domino server. That said, I'm not aware of any way to change that setting on the server either.

Comment: HTTPJVMMaxHeapSize is a parameter that can be set in the notes.ini for the server.  I found that. Some of my colleagues suggested a parameter file somehow associated to the server (perhaps through notes.ini) but no one knows exactly how this is supposed to be set up.

Comment: Since the JVM is closely integrated into the tasks in the Domino server, I'm not sure that IBM exposes a way to set other JVM parameters. I'm also not sure, by the way, that raising the HTTPJavaMaxHeapSize that high is really a good idea for a persistent JVM that never goes away. The last time I talked to any of the engineers at IBM (admittedly, at least 3 years ago), the Domino server's memory management was not really fully taking advantage of  64 bit address space. In any case, for something like this calling IBM support is likely the best way to go.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz According to this http://goo.gl/qxo5s, the param is ignored on x64 platforms (8G has no sense on 32bits): "This information is specific to Domino 8.5 and 8.5.1 for all Domino 32-bit platforms (Windows 32, AIX 32, Solaris and Linux). It does not apply to any Domino 64-bit platforms."

Answer (score 0):

You can set JVM properties as described here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/javauseroptionsfile

In your case, text file with content:

```
entityExpansionLimit = 4096000
```

and notes.ini param:

```
JavaUserOptionsFile=\notes\data\options.txt
```

should do it.

You can expect various side effects, because, JVM for `amgr` and `http` tasks share those properties and it may cause problems to fine tune your Domino server (when amgr and http require different settings).